# UK limited company and personal bank account

Tags: united-kingdom, bank-account

I have recently formed a UK limited company using an online company formation service. I currently do NOT live in the UK. I have not yet applied for a business bank account in the UK, but I do have a personal bank account with a UK bank. For various personal reasons I cannot travel to the UK for the next couple of months so I cannot arrange a meeting with a UK bank to apply for a business account.

My question is, am I able to use my personal bank account to receive payments for invoices issued by my company? If yes, is there a limitation on the total payments received, and how much? What are the complications for the accountant? Does the same apply for payments I do on behalf of my company, as expenses?

I do have an accountant but I would appreciate a piece of advice from a third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a legal requirement that you need a separate bank account. Just remember that you can only take money from your LLC as salary (paying tax), as dividend (paying tax), or as a loan (which you need to repay, including and especially if the LLC goes bankrupt). So make *very* sure that your books are in order.